# Sum column total by ID for each row for that ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to get the total weight for an order by summing all of the weights of the items in a separate column that repeats the order weight for each for of the order. I was able to get the total weight of each item in the order, qty * item weight, but I need a separate column that sums all of the item weights for the order.

Current query:

```
SELECT Transactions.Order, ItemFile.Weight * TransactionItems.QTY AS TotalItemWeight
FROM ItemFile INNER JOIN TransactionItems INNER JOIN Transactions ON TransactionItems.Order = Transactions.CNTR ON ItemFile.NUM = TransactionItems.ITEM
```

| ORDER | TOTALITEMWEIGHT |
| --- | --- |
| 197318 | 0 |
| 197318 | 600 |
| 197318 | 800 |
| 197318 | 196 |
| 197318 | 0 |
| 197318 | 14 |

Trying to achieve:

| ORDER | TOTALITEMWEIGHT | ORDERWEIGHT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 197318 | 0 | 1610 |
| 197318 | 600 | 1610 |
| 197318 | 800 | 1610 |
| 197318 | 196 | 1610 |
| 197318 | 0 | 1610 |
| 197318 | 14 | 1610 |

I tried a union all but it just adds another row with the order total. The system I'm loading this data into needs to look at a separate column with the total weight. Since the file will have multiple rows per order, the ORDERWEIGHT will be repeated for every line that corresponds to that order.

Comment: use the window function sum() over()    For example  sum(TOTALITEMWEIGHT) over (partition by order)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUM(<expr>) OVER(...)`. For example:

```
SELECT
  Transactions.Order, 
  ItemFile.Weight * TransactionItems.QTY AS TotalItemWeight,
  sum(ItemFile.Weight * TransactionItems.QTY) 
    over(partition by Transactions.Order) as orderweight
FROM ItemFile 
INNER JOIN TransactionItems 
INNER JOIN Transactions 
  ON TransactionItems.Order = Transactions.CNTR 
  ON ItemFile.NUM = TransactionItems.ITEM
```